# Transparent dijit.Dialog for Loader Image

Tags: javascript, dojo, modal-dialog, dojox.grid, dijit.form

I have Dojo Application in which on the left side there are some search Fields and on the right there is a grid which displays the result of search. 
I have implemented a Load Icon to display on the whole page until all the data is loaded on the grid and other widgets after search, basically I have used a dijit.Dialog and embedded a Loader Image(Similar to the Default Loader of Grid ) and shown when the search is executed and hiding when the data is loaded.
Loader Icon is working fine. I need to make the dialog Background Transparent so that I displays only the loader Image .

Below is the code of Dialog :

```
var txtContent = "<img src='images/loader.gif'/>";
        loaderDialog = dijit.byId('LoaderDialog');
        dijit.byId('LoaderDialog').attr("content", txtContent);
        dojo.style(dijit.byId("LoaderDialog").closeButtonNode,"display","none");
        loaderDialog.titleBar.style.display='none';
```

Just like the similar Icon as we see on Youtube While buffering.

Please guide.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use the 'standby' widget, instead of trying to 'trick' the dialog to do the same. See here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/widget/Standby.html